# failing to exucute command a second time

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

When i run this file and i choose option 1 and then again option 1. He runs sfc /scannow command. But when i ctrl+c and start over it gets stuck the moment he wants to run the sfc /scannow command.

```
  @echo off
cls

echo Welkom, Ik ben de ASCI Reparatie Tool.
echo Wat wil je doen?
echo 1. SFC 
echo 2. Bootrec
echo 3. Ping
echo 4. Robocopy
echo 5. 
echo 6.
echo 7.
echo 8.
echo 9.
CHOICE /C 123456789 /N /M "input nummer"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET KEUZE=GOTO SFC
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET KEUZE=GOTO bootrec
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET KEUZE=3
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET KEUZE=4
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET KEUZE=5
IF ERRORLEVEL 6 SET KEUZE=6
IF ERRORLEVEL 7 SET KEUZE=7
IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET KEUZE=8
IF ERRORLEVEL 9 SET KEUZE=9

:SFC 
cls
echo Je wilt dus dde SFC command gebruiken.
echo Welke parameter wil je gebruiken?
echo 1. /scannow 
echo 2. /verifyonly
echo 3. /scanfile
echo 4. /verifyfile
echo 5. /help
CHOICE /C 12345 /N /M "Input nummer"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET KEUZE=GOTO scan
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET KEUZE=GOTO only
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET KEUZE=GOTO file
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET KEUZE=GOTO verify
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET KEUZE=GOTO help

:scan

sfc /SCANNOW

pause

exit

:only

sfc /verifyonly

pause

exit

:file

sfc /scanfile

pause

exit

:verify

sfc /verifyfile

pause

exit

:help

sfc /help

pause

exit
```

ps This is my first script and i am not very familiar with making a batch file

Comment: i have don that because sfc needs to have admin before it can run. thus it is running both time as admin

Comment: So change `=GOTO` to `& GOTO` in your script logic.

Comment: done that and now he says "Environment variable KEUZE not defined".

Comment: and it work t the first time i run it but the second time it failed again. thus that isn't the problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the syntax for setting a variable and then going to a routine should be 
`IF ERRORLEVEL <#> SET <VarName>=<VarValue> & GOTO :<RoutineName>` maybe you just need `IF ERRORLEVEL <#> GOTO :<RoutineName>` and not need to set a value to the variable `KEUZE` so try .............. `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :scan`

Comment: thanks it makes the syntax alot cleaner but it dos not solve my problem.

Comment: when i run my script and at the end he is running sfc /scannow. i end it with ctrl+c. and after that if i want to run the script again the second time, when it should run sfc /scannow it only showes a blinking -

Comment: Don't break out the command window that is running `SCF /SCANNOW` and just let that run as expected. Breaking out of a command running in a command shell will stop the running command and the rest of the batch logic to stop executing. Just let the script follow the logic which appears to be run `SFC /SCANNOW` and once that finishes, `PAUSE` (you can press `Enter` here once paused) and then it will `EXIT`. Whatever you have scripted is what it will do, pressing Ctrl+c will likely break your batch script and/or the running command every time—the batch will not recover from this.

Comment: I can see you did not read the HELP files for the `IF` and `CHOICE` commands.  If you did you would see this from the `IF` help file. **ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number specified.** and you would see this from the `CHOICE` help file: **When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list them in decreasing order.**

Answer (score 1):

When using `CHOICE` and `IF ERRORLEVEL` you must do your errorlevel checks in descending order because the `IF` command will be true when the value is greater than or equal to the number specified in the `IF ERRORLEVEL` check.

```
 @echo off
 cls

 echo Welkom, Ik ben de ASCI Reparatie Tool.
 echo Wat wil je doen?
 echo 1. SFC 
 echo 2. Bootrec
 echo 3. Ping
 echo 4. Robocopy
 echo 5. 
 echo 6.
 echo 7.
 echo 8.
 echo 9.
 CHOICE /C 123456789 /N /M "input nummer"

 IF ERRORLEVEL 9 SET KEUZE=9 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET KEUZE=8 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 7 SET KEUZE=7 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 6 SET KEUZE=6 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET KEUZE=5 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET KEUZE=4 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET KEUZE=3 &GOTO :EOF
 IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO bootrec
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO SFC
 GOTO :EOF

 :SFC 
 cls
 echo Je wilt dus dde SFC command gebruiken.
 echo Welke parameter wil je gebruiken?
 echo 1. /scannow 
 echo 2. /verifyonly
 echo 3. /scanfile
 echo 4. /verifyfile
 echo 5. /help
 CHOICE /C 12345 /N /M "Input nummer"

 IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO help
 IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO verify
 IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO file
 IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO only
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO scan

 :scan
 sfc /SCANNOW
 pause
 exit

 :only
 sfc /verifyonly
 pause
 exit

 :file
 sfc /scanfile
 pause
 exit

 :verify
 sfc /verifyfile
 pause
 exit
```